# How to convert different files to pdf in ANDROID

Tags: android

I know that this question was asked many times before and that solutions to do this job were limited or unperfect. But I ask the question again because I think that since the time, it may be a real solution to convert different file formats (word, excel, image, ...) to pdf with the new android versions.
In other way, I can split the question to two ones :

how to convert MS files (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ...) to pdf in android?

how to convert images (jpeg, gif, ...) to pdf in android?

Comment: What I can come up with is: https://poi.apache.org/ images however can be accessed directly. So the task to generate pdf-files remains. correct?

Comment: I have  the same question here and I know that the WPS office app is doing the offline conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31437747/1616685

Comment: Finally I used the trial Aspose android components. It do a good job for converting doc, docx, xls and xlsx but now we have to purshase a license. But there is a bug with the conversion slides (ppt and pptx)